# Java iterate a list and add to object containing a list

Tags: java

I have few object say: Car, Auto and AutoCar

```
Car
- String name;
- String origin;

Auto
- String type;

AutoCar
-   String type;
-   List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Iterating for list of autos:

```
List<Car> carList = //fetched from a service or method
List<AutoCar> acList = new ArrayList<AutoCar>();

for(Auto auto : autos){
    AutoCar ac = new AutoCar();
    ac.setType(auto.getType());
    ac.setCars(carList);
    acList.add(ac);
}
```

I would expect result:

```
Type = CAR-Type-1
Cars:
name: FORD
origin: US
name: Suzuki
origin: Japan

Type = CAR-Type-2
Cars:
name: Volkswagen
origin: Germany
name: Audi
origin: Germany

Type = CAR-Type-3
Cars:
name: Jaguar
origin: UK
name: Ferrari
origin: Italy
```

But what I get is the last iteration preserved...

```
Cars:
name: Jaguar
origin: UK
name: Ferrari
origin: Italy
```

for all car Types (CAR-Type-1/CAR-Type-2/CAR-Type-3)

I think I am doing it wrong at this line:

```
ac.setCars(carList);
```

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: I don't think there is enough info here. Is `carList` correctly filled before you enter this loop? Are you updating it anywhere else? Can you check the value before it enters the loop?

Comment: do you want to get all cars of same type? or do I get you wrong?

Comment: You should get a new `carList` in each iteration of your loop; otherwise, you are setting the same list in all AutoCars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill `carList` for every `auto`. 
That means your service/method needs to accept a `type` parameter that returns all `Car` objects for that `type`, and you have to call it from within your loop over `autos`.

```
for (Auto auto : autos) {
  AutoCar ac = new AutoCar();
  ac.setType(auto.getType());
  ac.setCars(carService.getCarsByType(auto.getType())); //<-- your service/method call here
  acList.add(ac);
}
```

Comment: I accept this Answer. But I am actually struck on iterating and using the object in Hibernate which is more of a transnational issue I will have to resolve. Thanks.

Comment: That is different from what you initially asked, maybe you should ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `carList` for each auto, if you reuse the same every auto is going to have the same list of cars.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching `carList` only once and setting the same `carList` in the iterations. Fetch `carList` according to car type every time then set it accordingly.